# No Power to USB without a Device Plugged in on Boot

Tags: usb, 18.04, power-management, tlp

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04:
4.15.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 17 15:39:52 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

On a Razer Blade Pro and the following issue has come up.  My USB port doesn't receive power unless I have a device plugged in on boot.  If I boot up Ubuntu, then plug a USB device in (external hard drive, mouse receiver, etc) it won't work.

I've attached my TLP config.  The blacklist device is the Port that I was trying to get an external drive to work on and thought it was a power management issue with TLP.

Welcome ideas and am willing to post relevant logs, though I'm uncertain what is required for this.

Cheers

EDIT:
Some addition information.  It appears the issue starts with the computer coming out of Suspend.

I started the system with the drive plugged in, so it had power on boot and was recognized without a problem.  Before booting ubuntu though, I added usbcore.autosuspend=-1 to grub as this appeared as a possible way to resolve the issues.  However, when I put the computer into suspend (alt+shutdown from the gnome menu), the drive no longer powered on.  This is a bit strange as my USB ethernet cable as well as USB mouse work without a problem after coming out of suspend.

I also tried turning off Autosuspend in TLP for USB.  That didn't help either.

```
--- TLP 1.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ USB
Autosuspend         = enabled
Device whitelist    = (not configured)
Device blacklist    = 0bc2:ab30
Bluetooth blacklist = disabled
Phone blacklist     = disabled
WWAN blacklist      = enabled

Bus 002 Device 002 ID 8087:8000 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Intel Corp.  (hub)
Bus 002 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 001 Device 002 ID 8087:8008 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Intel Corp.  (hub)
Bus 001 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 004 Device 002 ID 0b95:1790 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet (ax88179_178a)
Bus 004 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0003 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 003 Device 004 ID 04f3:20b3 control = on,   autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Elan Microelectronics Corp.  (usbhid)
Bus 003 Device 003 ID 1532:011d control = on,   autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Razer USA, Ltd  (usbhid)
Bus 003 Device 007 ID 046d:c52b control = on,   autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver (usbhid)
Bus 003 Device 006 ID 0bda:579f control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Realtek Semiconductor Corp.  (uvcvideo)
Bus 003 Device 005 ID 8087:07dc control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Intel Corp.  (btusb)
Bus 003 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)
```